# How to fix "Found fs.readFile with non literal argument at index 0"?

Tags: node.js, eslint, typescript2.0, typescript-eslint

I am trying to add [eslint-plugin-security](https://github.com/nodesecurity/eslint-plugin-security) in a TypeScript project. However, for these codes

```
import { promises as fsp } from 'fs';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

const index = await fsp.readFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './index.html'), 'utf-8');
const key = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './ssl.key'));
await fsp.writeFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './sitemap.xml'), sitemap);
```

I got many these ESLint warnings:

> ```
> warning Found fs.readFile with non literal argument at index 0   security/detect-non-literal-fs-filename
> warning Found fs.readFileSync with non literal argument at index 0  security/detect-non-literal-fs-filename
> warning Found fs.writeFile with non literal argument at index 0  security/detect-non-literal-fs-filename
> ```

I found the document about this ESLint error at https://github.com/nodesecurity/eslint-plugin-security#detect-non-literal-fs-filename

But I still have no idea how to fix it. Any guide will be helpful! Thanks

---

**UPDATE**:

Found out as long as using passing the path returned by `path.join` or `path.resolve` will show this ESLint issue.

If I change to absolute path, the ESLint issue is gone. However, this loose the benefit of the relative path by `path.join` or `path.resolve`.

```
fs.readFileSync('/Users/me/project/ssl.key');
```

Looking for an alternative / better way if exists.

(Might be a false alarm? Asked at https://github.com/nodesecurity/eslint-plugin-security/issues/65)

Comment: @hongboo-miao have you got the fix for this? if yes please provide the answer.

Comment: @Vishnu unfortunately no. If I have solution, I will post here. BTW, track at the GitHub ticket I created https://github.com/nodesecurity/eslint-plugin-security/issues/65

Answer (score 0):

This was a false alarm, yes. It was fixed in https://github.com/eslint-community/eslint-plugin-security/pull/109 and released in `eslint-plugin-security@1.7.1` per [the project's changelog](https://github.com/eslint-community/eslint-plugin-security/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#171-2023-02-02).